# Run custom application (web page) on Skype incoming calls

Tags: skype

I want to open web browser with incoming number/name as parameter when somebody is calling to me through SkypeIn service (for small call center). 
I was looking through the Skype extras but I couldn't find anything relevant
How can I make that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an application that connects to a Skype client using the [Skype Public API](http://developer.skype.com/accessories). Your application can receive notifications on incoming calls. Search the Public API Reference for *call notifications* (I can't provide link, it's a ZIP file).

I hope that helps to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I have made sth like that:

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/41738/run-custom-apllication-in-skype-skypein/ and it works quite good